# Printooth character code don't work, need cyrillic

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, cyrillic

Displays characters when sending Cyrillic for printing.
I checked all available encodings in the library by printing the text "Тест" and got no result.

[image]

The printer supports the Cyrillic alphabet, I checked it on the application from the market:

[image]

Here is the part of the code where I set the print data:

```
public void testPrint(View view){    
     ArrayList<Printable> printables = getTestPrint("Тест");
     PairedPrinter printer = new PairedPrinter(name, mac);
     Printooth.INSTANCE.printer(printer).print(printables);
}

 public static ArrayList<Printable> getTestPrint(String text){

    ArrayList<Printable> printables = new ArrayList<>();

    Byte lineSpacing = (byte) Settings.lineSpacing(context);
    int spaceAfter = Settings.spaceAfter(context);

    printables.add(gerRawPrintable());

    Map<String, Byte> bytes = Printer.getCharacterCode();

    for(var entry: bytes.entrySet()){
        printables.add(new TextPrintable.Builder()
                .setText(entry.getKey() + " - " + text)
                .setCharacterCode((byte) entry.getValue())
                .setCustomConverter(new DefaultConverter())
                .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getALIGNMENT_LEFT())
                .setNewLinesAfter(spaceAfter)
                .setLineSpacing(lineSpacing)
                .build()
        );
    }

    return printables;

}

 public static RawPrintable gerRawPrintable(){
      return new RawPrintable.Builder(new byte[]{27, 100, 4}).build();
 }

  public static Printable getPrintElement(String text, Byte lineSpacing, byte characterCode){

      return new TextPrintable.Builder()
         .setText(text)
         .setAlignment(DefaultPrinter.Companion.getALIGNMENT_LEFT())
         .setNewLinesAfter(Settings.spaceAfter(MainActivity.context))
         .setLineSpacing(lineSpacing)
         .setCharacterCode(characterCode)
         .build();
  }

 public static Map<String, Byte> getCharacterCode(){
    Map<String, Byte> bytes = new HashMap<>();

    bytes.put("ARABIC CP720", DefaultPrinter.Companion.getCHARCODE_ARABIC_CP720());
    ...
    bytes.put("WEU", DefaultPrinter.Companion.getCHARCODE_WEU());

    return bytes;

}
```

Comment: You're *certain* that printer has a font that can do Cyrillic?

Comment: @g00se Yes, I checked on the application from the market.

Comment: ```.setText("\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442")``` make any difference? It has to be said that it's unfortunate that your image and code are not a pair. It would be better to show the result of your code

Comment: @g00se Good idea, after 8 hours I'll check and let you know, otherwise the printer is in the office.

I have updated the question.

Comment: OK but that's confusing. You've proved that the printer can do Cyrillic which is good but what we need is the simplest possible demonstration of what is wrong. There's far too much code there and what's shown image-wise doesn't (to me) reveal any problem

Comment: @g00se I checked with .setText("\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442") method but the result is the same: "5AB

Comment: As part of ```new TextPrintable.Builder()``` ? Also, what API is that?

Comment: @g00se this is Printooth library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by sending the text to print using the RavPrint class:

```
    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    printables.add(new RawPrintable.Builder(bytes).setNewLinesAfter(1).build());
```

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you got it working but that's a kludge. You should be able to set the default encoding to UTF-8 and forget about it and have all strings come out right

Comment: @g00se I also found out that this printer needs to be flashed for UTF, by default it does not support UTF. My customer told me this information after I found the solution. However, if you do not flash the printer, then my solution will still not work.

Comment: I'm confused. You said you got it working, with a 'manual' UTF-8 encoding, but you also say *if you do not flash the printer, then my solution will still not work*. But I think you have *not* flashed the printer have you?